# Where do biologists get information about mouse genes?

Tags: gene

From this article https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2005Sci...308.1909S/abstract

“We created transgenic mice that overexpress human catalase localized in the peroxisome, nucleus, or mitochondria (MCAT).”

How exactly do such changes occur step by step? Those. how did they find which genes needed to be changed in order to get the result in overexpression of catalase and in mitochondria?

I am new to biology, and although I understand, for example, how CRISPR works, it’s not clear where people get such data "this gene in the mouse is responsible for the expression of catalase in mitochondria. "Where to find such data?

Comment: When looking at the scientific literature, it's often helpful to looks at the Methods section to figure out how people did specific things. Unfortunately some journals aren't great about making the methods obvious, but for your paper it is accessible here: https://science.sciencemag.org/content/sci/suppl/2005/06/23/1106653.DC1/Schriner.SOM.pdf. Look at the section **Generation of Transgenic Mice **.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Potion and welcome to Biology Stack Exchange and biology in general!

To answer your questions, these changes do not occur. The authors of the publication have engineered "new" genes (also called transgenes in this context).

They have done so by fusion a portion of a of another gene (also called domain) to the beginning or the end of the sequence of the catalase gene. If your gene of interest is localized to a given organelle (for example mitochondria), you can also swap the domain which is responsible for the targeting to this particular organelle with one from a different gene you know goes for let's say peroxisomes.

If you want to know more details for this particular work I encourage you to check the supplementary material here: https://science.sciencemag.org/content/sci/suppl/2005/06/23/1106653.DC1/Schriner.SOM.pdf

Hope that helps!